# openni_tracker "Find user generator failed"

Tags: kinect, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I try to run `openni_tracker` as follows:

```
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

after I have launched

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

The problem is that when I run the tracker I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

Just in case: if I try to run it once more I get no respond and then:

```
[ERROR] InitFromXml failed: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!
```

I believe that "find user" error is generated from the line `150` of the file `openni_tracker.cpp` in `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/src`:

```
149: nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.Create(g_Context);
150: CHECK_RC(nRetVal, "Find user generator");
```

Which goes to a macro:

```
#define CHECK_RC(nRetVal, what)                                    \ 
    if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)                                      \
    {                                                                 \
        ROS_ERROR("%s failed: %s", what, xnGetStatusString(nRetVal)); \
        return nRetVal;                                               \
    }
```

So `g_UserGenerator.Create(g_Context)` for some reason returns not `XN_STATUS_OK`.

Maybe someone had that issue and knows how to resolve it.
As you may have noticed I run ros-fuerte.
Ubuntu 12.04

PS. I'm still fairly new to ROS, so any suggestions of actions that I can take are welcome :) I tried to change the file `openni_tracker.cpp` and recompile openni_tracker via `rosmake openni_tracker`, but that doesn't actually do the trick. Would be gratefull if someone could point me my mistakes. I know that there are a couple of questions that look like this one, but none of those is solved, though it's an important part of ros, I think. Thanks in advance.

`UPD:` I also experience this error on another ubuntu 12.04 PC in my lab. So it seems like this is fuerte+Ubuntu 12.04 issue. I don't have this error on Ubuntu 10.04 and ros-fuerte.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37615/openni_tracker-%22find-user-generator-failed%22/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been able to resolve the issue with [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuerteprecise/) post.

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install PrimeSense NITE using the following guide.

http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-kinect-openni-primesense/

PS. I skipped OpenNI and Kinect installation parts.

---

Originally posted by [Mahisorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/2624/mahisorn/) with karma: 31 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1